# ANY of given list in postgresql

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I have a table with char array field containing cities name and I have to return rows having exactly from given list.
for example
Table t1

```
 id | city
----+-------------------------
  1 | {Mumbai}
  2 | {Mumbai,Amritsar}
  3 | {Mumbai,Delhi}
  4 | {Delhi}
```

given list of cities are Mumbai, Delhi
output should be

```
 id | city
----+-------------------------
  1 | {Mumbai}
  3 | {Mumbai,Delhi}
  4 | {Delhi}
```

Please help if anyone has any idea. 
Thanks

Comment: You must show us your effort before getting any help from stackoverflow. I am sure that you can add a WHERE clause and check if any of the city is contained by the field.

Comment: select * from t1 where Array['Mumbai', 'Delhi']::varchar[] @> city;
this worked for me. posted in below.

Answer (score 0):

First u have to get the IDs that does not contain 'Mumbai' and 'delhi' and exclude them from table.

[Unnest()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-array.html) can be used to get individual elements from an array.

```
select id,city from table where id not in
       (select id from 
             (select id,unnest(city) as city from table)t
       where city not in ('Mumbai','delhi'));
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell from your question, the "is contained by" operator `<@` does what you want

```
create table bad_design (id integer, city text[]);
insert into bad_design 
values
(1, '{Mumbai}'),
(2, '{Mumbai,Amritsar}'),
(3, '{Mumbai,Delhi}'),
(4, '{Delhi}');

select *
from bad_design
where city <@ array['Mumbai', 'Delhi'];
```

returns:

```
id | city          
---+---------------
 1 | {Mumbai}      
 3 | {Mumbai,Delhi}
 4 | {Delhi}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from t1 
where Array['Mumbai', 'Delhi']::varchar[] @> city;
```

this will check values in DB belongs to the given list of items.